# Non-deprecated method for using ctrl-z to undo in a switch statement

Tags: java, swing, switch-statement, awt

I need to make my undo case in the switch work with ctrl-z, but all the methods I have tried are deprecated or don't work

```java
switch (event.getActionCommand()) {
       case "Undo":
            try {
              // undo method
            } catch(Exception e){
              // exception msg
            }
            break;

            case "Redo":
              try{
                // redo method
            } catch(Exception e){
               // exception msg
            }
            break;
 }
```

Currently, those are accessible through jmenu items, but I would like to have the under method also available via control z, the content that is undone and redone is inside a jframe.

Don't get me wrong, do they function correctly via their jmenu counterparts, I just cannot get them to work through key presses (ctrl+z)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just cannot get them to work through key presses (ctrl+z)

You need to add an "accelerator" to the menu item.

```
undoMenuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Z, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Enabling Keyboard Operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#mnemonic) for more information.

Comment: hadn't come across the accelerator thing yet, but have tried other similar methods. Thanks! Dont suppose you know how to prevent a redo if an action is performed after an undo by any chance?

Comment: Read the [Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). There is a section on `Text Component Features` that has a complete example using undo/redo.

Comment: was just wondering, made my own little thing for it, functional, but could probably be better